# Is it possible to force ubuntu to boot from optical drive

Tags: boot, uefi

Is it possible to force ubuntu to boot from optical media the next time it restarts?

**Background**
I upgraded a mac mini 2,1 (2007) by installing 14.04 and then upgrading through 16-18 to Ubuntu 20.4 lts. I want to clone the hdd to a new ssd and was hoping to use clonezilla's live dvd but while the dvd will boot on my windows laptop it doesn't boot on the mac mini. I get a screen asking me to select cd rom 1 or 2 (there is only 1 optical drive) but no keyboard input works, just like the screen mentioned here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mac_mini2-1/. I think its down to the UEFI being 32bit from Apple. (Side question Can I replace that ??)

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu. Would changing the startup disk on Ubuntu 20.04 to an optical drive mean it will boot from the dvd after any uefi or bios steps have completed and allow me to clone the HDD before restarting into Ubuntu again

Comment: Question seems fine to me.

Comment: @PixelatedFish well my message was primarily to close voters, since I found this in the close votes review queue, but given your subsequent message and the fact that you flagged the question to recommend closure, I should perhaps point out that it's completely against network policy to close on-topic questions that might possibly be better answered elsewhere. However, there's certainly nothing wrong with posting a comment to the effect that you'd recommend asking elsewhere, and I do the same occasionally, taking care to phrase the comment something like "this question is on topic here, but..."